# I am trying to install pygame using pycharm terminal but I get this error

Tags: python, module, pygame

I was trying to install pygame module using pycharm's terminal by typing "pip install pygame" but I am getting this error[installation error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQTTN.png) and yes I have tried running pycharm with admin perms and stuff but it did not work, if you can help then ty!

I just tried to use pygame by typing in my .py file "import pygame" but it say "no module called `pygame`" and I was simply trying to get a blank window

Comment: wich command do u run?

Answer (score 0):

just upgraded Python to latest version  updated pip by using,

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

after that simply run

```
pip install pygame
```

Make sure you are using the correct version of python and pygame that both are compatible with each other.

Comment: I am already at the latest version apparently.

Comment: have you made virtual env for your pygame?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you don't have admin privilege. Try to open the command prompt with Run as administrator mode or `pip install numpy --user`

Comment: Nope, I am admin.